# Database Updating

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a web app, where when a page loads, the address details are extracted from the database and displayed in the corresponding text-fields. However when I try to update and save the data, the data doesn't get updated.

However the same works fine when the extraction of data happens through the click of a button.

here's the code :

```
    public partial class Address : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string global;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            global = Session["ID"].ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server = INLD50045747A\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = MyDatabase;User ID = sa; Password = Welcome1; Trusted_Connection = False;");
            //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            con.Open();


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT PermanentAdd,PermanentAdd2, HomePlace, HomeState, HomePin FROM EMPLOYEE_FULLADDRESS_TABLE WHERE EmployeeID = '" + global + "'", con);

            SqlDataReader x = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (x.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text = (string)x["PermanentAdd"];
                TextBox1.Enabled = false;

                TextBox5.Text = (string)x["PermanentAdd2"];
                TextBox5.Enabled = false;

                TextBox2.Text = (string)x["HomePlace"];
                TextBox2.Enabled = false;

                TextBox3.Text = (string)x["HomeState"];
                TextBox3.Enabled = false;

                State.Items.FindByText(State.SelectedItem.Text).Selected = false;
                State.Items.FindByText(TextBox3.Text).Selected = true;
                State.Enabled = false;

                TextBox4.Text = (string)x["HomePin"];
                TextBox4.Enabled = false;
            }
            x.Close();
            con.Close();
        }


    }

    protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server = INLD50045747A\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = MyDatabase;User ID = sa; Password = Welcome1; Trusted_Connection = False;");
            //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            con.Open();
           // global = Session["ID"].ToString();


            //string insert = "UPDATE EMPLOYEE_FULLADDRESS_TABLE SET PermanentAdd = @PermanentAdd, PermanentAdd2 = @PermanentAdd2, HomePlace = @HomePlace, HomeState= @HomeState, HomePin= @HomePin where EmployeeID = '" + global + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE EMPLOYEE_FULLADDRESS_TABLE SET PermanentAdd = @PermanentAdd, PermanentAdd2 = @PermanentAdd2, HomePlace = @HomePlace, HomeState= @HomeState, HomePin= @HomePin where EmployeeID = '" + global + "'", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermanentAdd", TextBox1.Text);

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermanentAdd2", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePlace", TextBox2.Text);
            if (State.SelectedItem.Text == "--Select--")
            {
                State.SelectedItem.Text = TextBox3.Text;
            }
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeState", State.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomePin", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            lblmsg.Text = "DATA Updated Successfully";
            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = exp.Message;
            lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }



    }


   // static int count = 0;
    protected void EditButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

                TextBox1.Enabled = true;

                TextBox2.Enabled = true;
                //TextBox3.Enabled = true;
                TextBox4.Enabled = true;
                TextBox5.Enabled = true;
                State.Enabled = true;

    }
```

please help.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to show some code. There is no 'general' solution to this.

Comment: Sounds like you are not COMMITing your updates.

Comment: the code for the update database is working fine when i dont include the select command within the page_load function.However as soon as i have the select command within the page_load fn, the update button code works all fine but no change in data is seen within the databse.
Which part of the code is reqd, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have commented out your `global` / `employeeid` assignment?

`// global = Session["ID"].ToString();`

You should also change this to a parameter in your SQL.

Comment: Hey, chris, thanks a lott. that solves the lil mystery. the string global was inside the if(!IsPostBack) block.so it was getting the value only once during the page loading. so during updation it simply took a null value. problem solved. :)